# Proof of algebraic formula of variance without using linearity

Tags: proof-explanation, variance, expected-value

I have to proof the algebraic formula of the variance without using the linearity of expected values directly. So I can't use $\mathbb{E}(f\mathbb{E}(f)) = \mathbb{E}(f)\mathbb{E}(f)$. My given definition of the expected value is $\mathbb{E}(f) = \sum_{x}p(x)f(x)$.

I started with
$$\begin{align}
\text{Var}(f) &= \mathbb{E}((f - \mathbb{E}(f))^2)\\
&= \mathbb{E}(f^2 - 2f\mathbb{E}(f) + \mathbb{E}(f)^2)\\
&= \sum_{x}\left(p(x)(f(x)^2 - 2f(x)\mathbb{E}(f) + \mathbb{E}(f)^2)\right)\\
&= \sum_{x}\left(p(x)f(x)^2 - 2p(x)f(x)\mathbb{E}(f) + p(x)\mathbb{E}(f)^2\right)\\
&= \sum_xp(x)f(x)^2 - 2\mathbb{E}(f)\sum_xp(x)f(x) + \mathbb{E}(f)^2\sum_x p(x)\\
&= \mathbb{E}(f^2) - 2\mathbb{E}(f)\mathbb{E}(f) + \mathbb{E}(f)^2 \cdot 1\\
&= \mathbb{E}(f^2) - 2\mathbb{E}(f)^2 + \mathbb{E}(f)^2 = \mathbb{E}(f^2) - \mathbb{E}(f)^2
\end{align}$$

Is this proof correct?
The solution idea came to me while writing this question.

Comment: It  looks to me that you are simply restating E(fE(f))=E(f)E(f) in the middle term in your derivation.

Comment: Perhaps I expressed myself wrong. In many literature, the linearity of the expected values is introduced before the variance. So you can use the equation $\mathbb{E}(aX) = a\mathbb{E}(X)$. At the point of my exercise, there isn't any equation or calculation rule for expected values. So I've to proof the formula only with the axioms.

Comment: $E(f(E(f))=\sum p(x)f(x)E(f)=E(f)E(f)$, This is the heart of your proof.  Your derivation is correct, but I don't think it can be considered new in any way.  The key point is that $E(f)$ is independent of $x$.

Comment: Yeah the independence from $\mathbb{E}(f)$ from $x$ was the key point, why I hadn't any clue at the beginning of my proof. So this proof seems to suffice my requirements. And I hope, that this proof is not new in any way, because I only wanted a confirmation of the correctedness of my proof as it's an exercise for my understanding of some literature.

Comment: So do you want to make an official answer, so I can mark this question as solved? If not, I would delete this question, because for me it's solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E(f(E(f))=∑p(x)f(x)E(f)=E(f)E(f), This is the heart of your proof. Your derivation is correct, but I don't think it can be considered new in any way. The key point is that E(f) is independent of x.

Note that in general, many random variables have continuous distributions, so the sum becomes an integral.